# PHP Looping array data in a table format & an errant value

Tags: php, arrays, html-table

I have the following code. How can I get my results (`$x`) for the foreach function to print into the table at the top, but in columns instead of a straight horizontal row? Is there a way to do this without just inserting each individual value into the HTML table? I need to do the same for my `$employee['name']` variable but am not sure how I could get these values inserted into a table format without going one by one and entering the value myself.

Also, one value for `$x` at the end stays an integer and does not echo the string variable specified by the foreach function, is there a way I could fix this?

```
 <!--4.3--> 
     <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Employee name</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            <td>Type of Paying</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            <td><?php echo $x;?></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
        </tr> 
     </table>
</html>

<?php
foreach ($employees as $employee) {
    $x = ($employee['wage'] * $employee['hrs']) * 4;
    if ( 3000 <= $x ) {
        echo "High paying";
    } elseif (2000 <= $x && $x <= 2999) {
        echo "Good paying";
    } else {
        echo "Low paying";
    }
}
print_r ($x);
```

Comment: The `print_r ($x);` at the end will output the last value of `$x` as an integer.

Comment: Is there any reason why you have so many empty `<td></td>` bits in your table layout?

Comment: You have to evaluate your code a little bit. You have your table which echos the value of `x` but you're not setting `x` until after the table. Then at the end of your code, you're using `print_r` value of `x` after the loop has already been executed.

Comment: @NigelRen to create space between the columns. Its very much a jimmyrigged solution based on what little I know so far. I only know basic html, not css (I'll be learning it in another course), so I'm trying to do the best I can.

Comment: @spencdev oh right, I knew I wanted the table and I wanted to be sure that I made the function work before moving it. I'll move that above the table now. The echo inside the table was a test to see how it would print format wise.

Answer (score 0):

I inserted the foreach function into the table where I needed the results printed, then added 
 tags within the ifelse statement after each parameter, and it worked like a charm.

My code for that table now looks like this:

```
<html>
 <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Employee name</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
        <td>Type of Paying</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
        <td> <?php
foreach ($employees as $employee) {
    $x = ($employee['wage'] * $employee['hrs']) * 4;
    if ( 3000 <= $x ) {
        echo "High paying"; echo "<br/>";
    } elseif (2000 <= $x && $x <= 2999) {
        echo "Good paying"; echo "<br/>";
    } else {
        echo "Low paying"; echo "<br/>"; 
    }
}  echo "<br/>" ; ?>
</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr> 
 </table>
```

The other  section above the foreach function will hold employee names and is not yet filled out to match.